# How to read input XML for GET request using Jersey (REST)?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

want to read the input xml for get method using jax-rs, I know this is weird, but this is my requirement, I want to show user 400(bad request) if a user sends a body for REST GET method. So to throw a bad request if user sends a body, I need to first read the body.

Extracts from code written:

```
@GET
    @Path("{ids}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML, "multipart/form-data", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public Response read(InputStream inputStream, @PathParam("ids") String Ids, @Context HttpHeaders headers,
        @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @Context HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo)
    {.........//Code here
```

So I try to read inputStream like :

```
//Some Code here    
 try
                {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //exception handling
                }
//Some code here
```

Whether the request contains, body or not, it is always returning blank to me after reading inputStream.

SO my question is how can I check if an xml body is sent in GET request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InputStream actually reads the body of the request. Now, GET requests are not really supposed to have a body. So, it might be that jersey just strips the body. Also, what client are you using to issue the request?

If you need the body, I'd suggest using POST or PUT depending on your situation.

Comment: Can you please tell me surely if jersey strips the body for GET and Delete requests ?

Comment: Just tested this and Jersey does not strip the body. However, it does issue an warning when the resources are being deployed. So, you should be able to read in the body content. I tested with `curl -X GET -v --data-binary @hello.scala http://localhost:8081/webservice/`